# Return all columns from a table but only return rows where a specific column is distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am making a shopping cart application of sorts, so when a user logs in whether or not he orders anything he is assigned an `OrderNumber`. When he places items in his cart the order is stored in the database like so:

```
+---+------------+-----------+------------+
|num|CustomerItem|OrderNumber|CustomerName|
+---+------------+-----------+------------+
|1  |Candles     |12         |Dorothy     |
+---+------------+-----------+------------+
|2  |Keyboard    |11         |Kirk        |
+---+------------+-----------+------------+
|3  |Lotion      |12         |Dorothy     |
+---+------------+-----------+------------+
|4  |Monitor     |11         |Kirk        |
+---+------------+-----------+------------+
|5  |Cups        |13         |Kathy       |
+---+------------+-----------+------------+
```

Now, This is what I would like to return

```
+---+------------+-----------+------------+
|num|CustomerItem|OrderNumber|CustomerName|
+---+------------+-----------+------------+
|4  |Monitor     |11         |Kirk        |
+---+------------+-----------+------------+
|1  |Candles     |12         |Dorothy     |
+---+------------+-----------+------------+
|5  |Cups        |13         |Kathy       |
+---+------------+-----------+------------+
```

These statements are what I have tried:

```
select * from [mytable] where
[OrderNumber] in (Select max(OrderNumber) FROM [mytable] group by OrderNum)
```

And

```
select * from [mytable] where
[OrderNumber] in (Select Distinct OrderNumber FROM [mytable] group by OrderNum)
```

Neither statement will work, they both show duplicates in the `OrderNumber` Column

Comment: You need to give us, and eventually, SQL Server, a rule for *which* other column values to select for a particular `OrderNumber`. Should it be all of the column values for the row with the highest `num` value? Should it be whatever `MAX()` returns for each column. Define a rule, and it has to be based on the data available in these columns.

Comment: (I've realised my first suggestion doesn't match your desired output since it would return the row with `num` 3 rather than 1)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to try something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [mytable]
WHERE ([OrderNumber], num) IN (
    SELECT OrderNumber, max(Numb) 
    FROM [mytable] 
    GROUP BY OrderNum
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for distinct http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

```
select distinct customeritem ,ordernnumber,customername
from [mytable]
```

This will give a disitinct list over the items ordered.    You are going to loose the num(PK) column this way but there is no real way to get that becouse its going to be unique so it wont be a duplicate.   You could add a group by and a count(*) to get how many they ordered

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted the rows with the highest `num` values for a particular `OrderNumber` (this doesn't match your expected results, but you've yet to articulate a rule) then:

```
; With Ordered as (
 Select *,
 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OrderNum
                    ORDER BY num desc) as rn
 FROM [mytable]
)
select * from Ordered where rn = 1
```

See [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Since the **CustomerName** is the same for each row per **OrderNumber**, you need to make a rule for determining which **Num** and **CustomerItem** will be returned.

But looking at your desired sample output, you use a different logical rule for each.

Example:

```
[Num]        [CustomerItem]      [OrderNumber]       [CustomerName]
1            Candles             12                  Dorothy
2            Keyboard            11                  Kirk
3            Lotion              12                  Dorothy
4            Monitor             11                  Kirk
```

You wanted to return these two:

```
4            Monitor             11                  Kirk    
1            Candles             12                  Dorothy
```

Now For **Monitor**, both the Num and CustomerItem represent the first result in a descending order whichever field you use to order it. For **Candles**, both Num and CustomerItem represent ASCENDING order. So either there's another reason for the ordering which we do not know, or what you're asking for is illogical.

Otherwise you could simply do something like this for instance:

```
select DISTINCT CA.*
from [mytable] MT
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM mytable T2 WHERE T2.OrderNumber = MT.OrderNumber ORDER BY T2.Num asc) CA
```

Which would return the first row for each group of OrderNumbers, ordered by Num. For a larger table, joining myTable to a sub query with GROUP BY OrderNumber and MAX(Num), using those two as joining values, would create the same result but be more efficient.